# Ensuring Ubuntu docker image will not kill the process under heavy load

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, ubuntu

We run our app as a daemon (or some times with `nohup` command) so that Ubuntu will not kill this process under heavy processor and memory load. However, we want to dockerize (on Ubuntu 20.04 docker image) our app. We have created the docker image for it. How can we ensure similar behavior inside docker container? Will setting running the process as docker entrypoint be sufficient or we have run it as a daemon even from entrypoint?